# How would you implement a heuristic search in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, search, functional-programming, heuristics

In Haskell or some other functional programming language, how would you implement a heuristic search?

Take as an example search space, the nine-puzzle, that is a 3x3 grid with 8 tiles and 1 hole, and you move tiles into the hole until you have correctly assembled a picture. The heuristic is the "Manhattan heuristic", which evaluates a board position adding up the distance each tile is from its target position, taking as the distance the number of squares horizontally plus the number of squares vertically each tile needs to be moved to get to the correct location.

I have been reading John Hughes paper on pretty printing as I know that pretty printer back-tracks to find better solutions. I am trying to understand how to generalise a heuristic search along these lines.

===

Note that my ultimate aim here is not to write a solver for the 9-puzzle, but to learn some general techniques for writing efficient heuristic searches in FP languages. I am also interested to learn if there is code that can be generalised and re-used across a wider class of such problems, rather than solving any specific problem.

For example, a search space can be characterised by a function that maps a State to a List of States together with some 'operation' that describes how one state is transitioned into another. There could also be a goal function, mapping a State to Bool, indicating when a goal State has been reached. And of course, the heuristic function mapping a State to a Number reflecting how well it is estimated to score. Other descriptions of the search are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessarily very specific to FP or Haskell (unless you utilize lists as "multiple possibility" monads, as in [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-list-monad)).

One way to do it would be by writing a recursive function taking the following:

- the current state (that is the board configuration)
- possibly some path metadata, e.g., the number of steps from the initial configuration (which is just the recursion depth), or a memoization-map of all the states already considered
- possibly some decision, metadata, e.g., a pesudo-random number generator

Within each recursive call, the function would take the state, and check if it is the required result. If not it would

- if it uses a memoization map, check if a choice was already considered
- If it uses a recursive-step count, check whether to pursue the choices further
- If it decides to recursively call itself on the possible choices emanating from this state (e.g., if there are different tiles which can be pushed into the hole), it could do so in the order based on the heuristic (or possibly pseudo-randomly based on the order based on the heuristic)

The function would return whether it succeeded, and, if they are used, updated versions of the memoization map and/or pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: The list monad and knights quest sections from your link are useful to me, thanks.